# awk to find and output differences in files

Tags: awk

I am trying to find the differences between `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and output the differences. I tried `diff` and `sed` and the output does not return any differences.  I also tried `awk` and matching on `$2`, but I think the syntax is wrong as a file gets created but it is 0kb.  The actual data I am using is quite large but I know there should be 18 differences.  Thank you :).

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} !($2 in a){print $2}' file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt
```

**file1.txt**

```
chr1    955542  955763
chr1    957570  957852
chr1    976034  976270
```

**file2.txt**

```
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1
chr1    957570  957852  +   AGRN:exon.2
chr1    976034  976270  +   AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4
chr1    976542  976787  +   AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.5
chr1    976847  977092  +   AGRN:exon.6
```

**Desired output**

```
chr1    976542  976787  +   AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.5
chr1    976847  977092  +   AGRN:exon.6
```

**Diff result** (since these are the two records that are not in both files)

```
1,52058c1,52040
< chr1  955542  955763
< chr1  957570  957852
< chr1  976034  976270
```

Comment: why isn't `diff file1.txt file2.txt` working ?

Comment: I tried that and the result returned was everything in the file not the differences.  Thank you :).

Comment: what difference you expect?  Based on the script you are checking second field so no difference is expected since they are matching.

Comment: There should be 18 differences out of 52,000 lines.  File1.txt is 52,058 entries and file2.txt has 52,040 entries in it.  I am trying to find out what the 18 are.  `$2` could be used as that field is in both files.  If there is a difference on that field then the entire line is outputted to a new file.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris - no, we are not asking about differences between files we can't see. We are asking what the differences are between the files you posted that we CAN see and what the expected output would be given those files. That is all we have to go on and its what we'd be testing a potential solution against. If those files don't represent your real input and demonstrate the problem, then edit your question to fix that.

Comment: I added the results of the `diff` command in the original post.  Thank you :).

Comment: There is no way diff is outputting what you posted given the input files you posted. Every line is different between those files so diff will output all lines from both files. Is it supposed to be your desired rather than actual output? Please THINK about what you are telling us and edit you question to make it CLEAR!

Comment: I added some more details to the files and the desired output.  I hope it is more clear and thank you all :).

Comment: It is a bit, I think, but now you'd just have to change `!($2 in a){print $2}` to `!($2 in a){print $0}` (idiomatically just `!($2 in a)`) and your originally posted script would work and I'm sure that would have been obvious to you if that was really your problem so I guess there must be something else still going on that so far you haven't been able to communicate.

Comment: Is every line treated as different by `diff` because `file1.txt` is 3 fields and `file2.txt` is 5 lines.  Thank you :).

Comment: Yes, of course, lines containing dfferent text from each other are different and so `diff` will output them. I still have no idea what `Diff result (since these are the two records that are not in both files)` means or is intended to show us. I posted an answer, if it's not what you want please edit your question again to clarify further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm curious while diff isn't working like you want, but your awk logic isn't correct:

You're checking the second field's (delimited by spaces) value only.  In your example the second field is all identical so nothing is being printed out.  Using the whole line instead works as expected:

Using your example text where all is different:

```
$ cat file1.txt
chr1 955542 955763
chr1 957570 957852
chr1 976034 976270

$ cat file2.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 957570 957852 + AGRN:exon.2
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt

$ cat diff.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 957570 957852 + AGRN:exon.2
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4
```

Here's with the second line identical just to show it working in a more obvious way.

```
$ cat file1.txt
chr1  955542 955763
chr1  957570 957852
chr1  976034 976270

$ cat file2.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 957570 957852
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt

$ cat diff.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4
```

**EDIT**

Based on a comment stating:
"There should be 18 differences out of 52,000 lines. File1.txt is 52,058 entries and file2.txt has 52,040 entries in it. I am trying to find out what the 18 are"

Given you said file1 has more lines, you need to process file2 first.  The first file read is populating the array and then the second is checking for lines existing in that array.  You need to process the smaller file first so that the additional lines you're interested in aren't in the array.  It'd be the same logic above, just with the file order switched, e.g.:

```
$ cat file1.txt
chr1 955542 955763
chr1 957570 957852
chr1 976034 976270
New Line!
Not in file2!

$ cat file2.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 957570 957852
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt > diff.txt

$ cat diff.txt
chr1 955542 955763
chr1 976034 976270
New Line!
Not in file2!

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt

$ cat diff.txt
chr1 955542 955763 + AGRN:exon.1
chr1 976034 976270 + AGRN:exon.2;AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.4
```

Note that reading file1 first doesn't emit the additional lines.

If you don't care about the additional text on the lines, just the text in the second field, then you could use $2 as you originally did.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} !($2 in a)' file1 file2
chr1    976542  976787  +   AGRN:exon.3;AGRN:exon.5
chr1    976847  977092  +   AGRN:exon.6
```